# Linux: Loop using foldername when finding file

Tags: linux, loops, directory

I'm currently trying to use the following linux script to loop through folders and perform calculations using a function:

```
for f in s*
do
    echo "You are in the following folder - $s" 
    cd $s

    # FUNCTION SHOULD BE HERE

    cd /C/Users/Eric/Desktop/Files
done
```

The problem: How can I use the foldername to find the correct file? For example, the foldername is `scan1` and I want to use the file called `gaf_scan1_recording_mic.nii` for the function.

Thanks a lot,

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, `$var` and `${var}` are the same (*the braces are only needed for ambiguity in the expressions*):

```
var=test
echo $var
# test
echo ${var}
# test
echo $varworks
# prints nothing (there is no variable 'varworks')
echo ${var}works
# testworks
```

You can use the folder name like this (`gaf_${f}_recording_mic.nii`):

```
for f in *; do
    # Check if $f is a directory
    if [[ -d $f ]]; then
        echo "You are in the following folder - $f" 
        cd $f
        # The filename to use for your function
        do_stuff gaf_${f}_recording_mic.nii
    fi
done
```